# Fraction of blackbody energy below the peak of the blackbody curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I don't know how to determine the fractions of blackbody energy that lie below and above the peak of the blackbody curve.
Should I use the Planck distribution to solve this problem?

Comment: Please read our [FAQ on writing question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: Rob's advice is correct. Note the Planck function has some awfully large factors in it - be careful about how you evaluate it for small lambda so it doesn't blow up - or at least gives you numerical instability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Wien's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law) to calculate the wavelength, $\lambda_\text{max}$ at the peak of the blackbody (Planck) distribution.

You then need to integrate the Planck function from 0 to $\lambda_\text{max}$ and $\lambda_\text{max}$ to infinity.

You can check your results against a rough table of similar results in the Wikipedia page on the Planck function, parameterized in terms of temperature.